# Azure AD: why manifest has empty keyCredentials after running New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Or is it ok for the keyCredentials to be empty?
*Probably the first step is where it went wrong, but not sure yet.*

**Expected Result:** Application Manifest has Cert Secrets in keyCredentials, so that application can perform Tokenized authentication as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/)

**Actual Result:** keyCredentials is empty

**Step1**:  create application in AD by running :

```
$azureAdApplication=New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "SetupTest1008" -HomePage "http://www.SetupTest8.com" -IdentifierUris "http://SetupTest8" -Password "SetupTest1234"
$azureAdApplicationPrincipal=New-AzureADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId
```

***Notes***:
according to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/), $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId will be used to upload the cert secret

**Step2**: ready the cert secret

```
.\makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=123456" -b 12/15/2014 -e 12/15/2016 -ss my -len 2048 c:\tmp\123456.cer

connect-msolservice -credential $credentials
$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
$cer.Import("c:\tmp\123456.cer")
$binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert);
```

**Step3**: upload the cert secret

```
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId
$azureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue -Usage verify
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is some confusion between two separate directory objects that we have in AAD that represent your Application:

1. Application Objects (Global - Related to Manifest)
2. Service Principals (Local - Related to MSOL CMDLETS)

We have a more formal description of Application Objects and Service Principals [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-objects/) but I will attempt to give you some more general differences between these objects, and some specific examples that address what you are seeing here with certs.

Application Objects are global representations of your application in the directory. When you, as an application developer, register your application using the Azure Management Portal, you are creating an Application Object in your developer tenant, which can be used to store global properties about your application. In addition a service principal gets created in your tenant, and if you are an administrator, it stores the implicit consent the application has to access your tenant. This is why applications that are created by tenant administrator's do not prompt their users for consent.

Now lets say you made your application multi-tenant, and there is a user in another tenant that wants to use it. Because you have a **global** application object registered in your home tenant, other users can discover and login to your application. They, being outside of your tenant, would need to consent to your application, but if they do, then a **local** service principal gets created in the second tenant that represents your application in that tenant. Not only does this object store the consent a user/admin gave to your application, but it can also be used to store tenant specific properties. For example, if you wanted to add vanity/tenant-specific domains and urls for a certain tenant, you would NOT want to register these properties on your global object, but just on the local service principal for that tenant so only they can use those urls.

Getting back to your specific case, you may want to provision tenant specific certificates that your application can authenticate with based on how your service is deployed to other tenants. In this situation, you would have an admin of the external tenant use MSOL PowerShell the way you described in your question, and they would be able to add a certificate to their Service Principal. This cert can be used to authenticate your application in the context of this one tenant, but cannot be used outside of this tenant because it is only registered locally on the service principal.

If, on the other hand, you wanted to update your global certificate so that you can use a new key to authenticate in the context of ANY tenant, then you would make a change to your Application Object which is accessible through your Application Manifest in the Azure Management Portal.

This is why you do not see changes done by AAD PowerShell affecting your Manifest: Ultimately, you are changing two different objects that both represent your application in different contexts.

If you need a programmatic way of modifying your Application Object, I recommend you use the Graph API. Unfortunately, AAD PowerShell does not currently support reading/modifying your application object, but that should come in the future. Here are some details on the [application entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#ApplicationEntity) as exposed through the Graph API. You should look to make a POST/PATCH on the keyCredentials property.

I hope this helps,
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Thanks Shawn for such thorough illustration! I will have to find some time to go through your great enlightenment, sorry for the delay.